# FROM keyword not found where expected, text selection Oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, concatenation, clob

I want to produce a table which contains substrings and IDs of another table, where the substrings occur. See question [Concatenate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44626050/concatenate-values-of-field-depending-on-text-selection-oracle-sql/44632363#44632363).

```
create table table_expressions
(
A clob
);

insert all
  into table_expressions (a) values ('atveroeosipsum')
  into table_expressions (a) values ('test') 
  into table_expressions (a) values ('stetclitakasd') 
  into table_expressions (a) values ('noseatakimata') 
  into table_expressions (a) values ('loremipsumdolor') 
  into table_expressions (a) values ('consetetursadipscingelitr') 
select * from dual;

create table a_x
(
A clob,
B clob
);

insert all
  into a_x (a, b) values('atveroeosipsumloremipsumdolor', 1)
  into a_x (a, b) values('stetclitakasdtest', 2) 
  into a_x (a, b) values('noseatakimataatveroeosipsum', 3)
  into a_x (a, b) values('loremipsumdolor', 4)
  into a_x (a, b) values('consetetursadipscingelitr', 5)
select * from dual;

create table a_y 
  as 
  with 
  input_strings ( a ) as ( 
select column_value from table_expressions 
  ) 
select t2.a, listagg(t1.b, ',') within group (order by t1.b) 
 as ids from a_x t1 join input_strings t2 on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%' 
 group by t2.a
```

The `table_expressions` contains the desired substrings
My real data produce quite a lot IDs to be concatenated. After running the code with the real data the error `01489. 00000 -  "result of string concatenation is too long"
*Cause:    String concatenation result is more than the maximum size.
*Action:   Make sure that the result is less than the maximum size.` occurs.

How could I rewrite the code in order to format the resulting column `IDs` in CLOB format?
I looked at question [Listagg function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13795220/listagg-function-result-of-string-concatenation-is-too-long) but I didn't understand the code in the posted answer.

This code:

```
create table a_y
as
with
 input_strings ( a ) as (
   select a
   from table_expressions                    
 )
select   t2.a, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY t1.a).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST as ids
from     a_x t1 
     join input_strings t2 on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
group by t2.a
;
```

produces error `FROM keyword not found where expected`. 
I would like to produce a table a_y, which should look like that and columns `A` ans `IDs` should be in clob format:

```
A                            | IDs                                    
-----------------------------|-------
atveroeosipsum               | 1,3
test                         | 2
stetclitakasd                | 2
noseatakimata                | 3
loremipsumdolor              | 1,4
consetetursadipscingelitr    | 5
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do the string fragments in `table_expressions` have to be CLOBs? It would seem to make sense that they would be relatively short strings (not longer than 4000 characters).

Comment: It might be that they are longer than that. The column of the real data is in CLOB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate error is caused by having two aliases given to the result of the concatenation:  You have `AS LIST as ids`. You can't give two aliases to the result of a calculation. If you want the newly created table to have a column `LIST` then delete `as ids`, and vice versa.

Then you will run into another error: you are attempting to `ORDER BY t1.a` in the aggregation. That won't work; you can't order by a CLOB in the XML aggregation. Do you really care in what order the aggregation happens? If you don't, change to `ORDER BY NULL`. If you do care, you have a problem, since in Oracle an `order_by_clause` simply cannot order by a CLOB expression. You will have to create a separate column for ordering by using other methods.

In the solution overall, there is no need for the WITH clause. Wherever you refer to "input_strings" in the query (other than the WITH clause), simply write "table_expressions".

**EDIT**

Here is how this could be made to work. First I will show the CREATE TABLE statements. I will assume that `table_expressions` has a CLOB column of search strings, and that there are NO DUPLICATES in this column. Even so, the table also needs a separate primary key, of a data type that is not LOB or other long, not-standard-type. I use NUMBER for this.

Then I aggregate by this primary key column. Alas, I can't select the search string at the same time. I could `SELECT MAX(t2.a)` but that doesn't work with CLOB values either! Instead, I need a further join to match the primary key to the search string. (Sorry, the query will take that much longer because of this...)

In the aggregation, I sort by the first 4000 characters of the string value from column `a`. This is not as good as sorting by the entire input string, but it is still better than ordering by NULL.

```
create table a_x ( a, b ) as
  select to_clob('atveroeosipsumloremipsumdolor'), 1 from dual union all
  select to_clob('stetclitakasdtest')            , 2 from dual union all
  select to_clob('noseatakimataatveroeosipsum')  , 3 from dual union all
  select to_clob('loremipsumdolor')              , 4 from dual union all
  select to_clob('consetetursadipscingelitr')    , 5 from dual
;

create table table_expressions ( a, pk ) as 
 select to_clob('atveroeosipsum') , 10 from dual union all 
 select to_clob('test') , 11 from dual union all 
 select to_clob('stetclitakasd') , 12 from dual union all 
 select to_clob('noseatakimata') , 13 from dual union all 
 select to_clob('loremipsumdolor') , 14 from dual union all 
 select to_clob('consetetursadipscingelitr'), 15 from dual 
 ;

create table a_y as
select te.a, s.ids
from   table_expressions te 
       join
       (select   t2.pk, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') 
                     ORDER BY cast(t1.a as varchar2(4000))).GetClobVal(),',') as ids
        from     a_x t1 
         join table_expressions t2 
          on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
         group by t2.pk
       ) s
on te.pk = s.pk
;
```

Now let's check what we got:

```
select * from a_y;

A                          IDS
-------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------
atveroeosipsum             atveroeosipsumloremipsumdolor,noseatakimataatveroeosipsum
test                       stetclitakasdtest
stetclitakasd              stetclitakasdtest
noseatakimata              noseatakimataatveroeosipsum
loremipsumdolor            atveroeosipsumloremipsumdolor,loremipsumdolor
consetetursadipscingelitr  consetetursadipscingelitr
```

**EDIT #2**

If you need to concatenate the id's from table `a_x` (column `b`), not the CLOBs themselves, then replace `t1.a` with `t1.b` (and, in the `ORDER BY` clause of `XMLAGG`, you don't need any `cast`, just `order by t1.b`).

```
drop table a_y purge;

create table a_y as
select te.a, s.ids
from   table_expressions te 
       join
       (select   t2.pk, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.b,',').EXTRACT('//text()') 
                     ORDER BY t1.b).GetClobVal(),',') as ids
        from     a_x t1 
         join table_expressions t2 
          on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
         group by t2.pk
       ) s
on te.pk = s.pk
;

select * from a_y;

A                          IDS
-------------------------  ---
atveroeosipsum             1,3
test                       2
stetclitakasd              2
noseatakimata              3
loremipsumdolor            1,4
consetetursadipscingelitr  5
```

Comment: I modified the code: `create table a_y
    as
    with
     input_strings ( a ) as (
       select a
       from table_expressions                    
     )
    select   t2.a, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY NULL).GetClobVal(),',') as ids
    from     a_x t1 
         join table_expressions t2 on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
    group by t2.a
    ;`. There's an error `inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s`. I don't get it with `with`.

Comment: You may leave out `with input_strings ( a ) as ( select a from table_expressions )` since it is no longer needed. But this unneeded WITH clause is not the reason for the error. The error message should tell you exactly where it is occurring - does it? What line and position. Perhaps in a non-obvious way, something like  Error(13:48) (meaning line 13, 48th character of that line of code).

Comment: Now I changed it to : `create table a_y
    as
    select   t2.a, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY NULL).GetClobVal(),',') as ids
    from     a_x t1 
         join table_expressions t2 on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
    group by t2.a
    ;`. It is the line `group by t2.a` that the error refers to. Is it not possible to group?

Comment: Yes, I have a primary key and I changed the table to `create table table_expressions
(
A clob,
PK varchar2(4000)
);

insert all
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('atveroeosipsum', 1)
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('test', 2) 
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('stetclitakasd', 3) 
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('noseatakimata', 4) 
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('loremipsumdolor', 5) 
      into table_expressions (a, pk) values ('consetetursadipscingelitr', 6) 
select * from dual;` The error still occurs.

Comment: I think I have a workaround, I will post it in my Answer above.

Comment: I then changed the format of `pk` to `number(20)` and my code to `create table a_y
    as
    select   t2.a, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY NULL).GetClobVal(),',') as ids
    from     a_x t1 
         join table_expressions t2 on t1.a like '%' || t2.a || '%'
    group by t2.pk
    ;` The error is now `"not a GROUP BY expression"` in the line `select   t2.a , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,', ...`

Comment: @yPennylane - right. `t2.a` is not included in GROUP BY (because it can't, that was the problem to begin with). Normally you would include `max(t2.a)` in `SELECT` (it is unique anyway), but `max()` doesn't work on CLOBs either. Please see how I work around all these problems in the Answer above.

Comment: ok. so only the ids of the expressions need to be assigned to column IDs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147845/discussion-between-mathguy-and-ypennylane).

Comment: mathguy, I posted something in the chat

Comment: `create table a_y as select te.a, s.ids from table_expressions te join (select t2.pk, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,t1.a,',').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY t1.b).GetClobVal(),',') as ids from a_x t1 join table_expressions t2 on t1.b like '%' || t2.a || '%' group by t2.pk ) s on te.pk = s.pk ;` produces an empty table.

Comment: @yPennylane I explained the empty table in the chat, and posted the full solution in the Answer.